# exclusions do not work in my Code coverage when I migrated from SonarSource to SonarQube

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage

I migrated from SonarSource to SonarQube V4.5.1. I have a problem in my code coverage measurements. It does not take into account my exclusions. Here is my setup to Jenkins OK and **SonarSource OK**:

**in Jenkins configuration (Exclusions (e.g.: **/*Test*.class) field):**

```
**/*AppConfig.*,fr/company/prj/jersey/uri/**/*
```

**in pom.xml file:**

```
<properties>
    <sonar.jacoco.excludes>**/*AppConfig.*</sonar.jacoco.excludes>
    <sonar.exclusions>fr/company/prj/jersey/uri/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```

Here is my setup to Jenkins OK and **SonarQube KO**:

**in Jenkins configuration (Exclusions (e.g.: **/*Test*.class) field):**

```
**/*AppConfig.*,fr/company/prj/jersey/uri/**/*
```

**in pom.xml file:**

```
<properties>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/*AppConfig.*</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    <sonar.exclusions>fr/company/prj/jersey/uri/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```

I tested via SonarQube administration page but do not work:

General settings > Exclusions > Code Coverage > Coverage Exclusions : **/*AppConfig.*

General settings > Exclusions > Files > Source File Exclusions : fr/company/prj/jersey/uri/**/*

Comment: As SonarSource is the company behind formerly Sonar and now SonarQube, what are you calling SonarSource in your question ?

Comment: Hello benzonico, it's good that you reply to this email. I saw you at breizhCamp of Rennes (France). How to post a comment on the site http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions ?

Comment: best way is to reach the google groups indicated here : www.sonarqube.org/get-support/